# /Account/Login Post Method return 500

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

i have struggling with this for two days now. my angular app work perfectly with my idenity server implementation. All working good in my local system. but when i hosted it in azure the Identity Server MVC Login Page is returning 500 Error. You can take a look at the url below:

1. Angular Url: https://oyserms.azurewebsites.net
2. Identity Server Login Url: https://oysermsauth.azurewebsites.net/Account/Login.

Either using the correct credentials or not the same error display(ERROR: Sorry, there was an error. The error is not specific). Have tried all i could because not result.

Please kindly assist. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried checking the web app service logs? You can enable them under Monitoring > App Service logs > Application Logging (Filesystem). Then view them from the Log Stream.

Comment: Below is what i get in the log
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.

Most likely causes:
IIS received the request; however, an internal error occurred during the processing of the request. The root cause of this error depends on which module handles the request and what was happening in the worker process when this error occurred.
IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site or application.

Comment: The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL.
The request is mapped to a managed handler but the .NET Extensibility Feature is not installed.

Things you can try:
Ensure that the NTFS permissions for the web.config file are correct and allow access to the Web server's machine account.
Check the event logs to see if any additional information was logged.
Verify the permissions for the DLL.

Comment: Install the .NET Extensibility feature if the request is mapped to a managed handler.
Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click here.

Comment: @ChrisEdgington: Am confused i dont know how to go about all this. The above is what i found in the log

Comment: @ChrisEdgington: Also i Have Below Details too

Detailed Error Information:
Module    AspNetCoreModuleV2
Notification    ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler    aspNetCore
Error Code    0x00000000
Requested URL    https://oysermsauth:80/Account/Login
Physical Path    D:\home\site\wwwroot\Account\Login
Logon Method    Anonymous
Logon User    Anonymous